# I cant use the function argument in my code

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

**my javascript code is**

```
    $(document).ready(function today(tony){
    var mytext = tony;
    $('#tod').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    url:"/ajaxdemo",
    data:{text:mytext},
    method:"POST",
    success: function(res){
        alert(res.from)
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err)
    }

})
```

})
})

**my html code is**

```
<a id="tod" href="" onclick="today(tony)" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>{{this.tod}}</a>
```

**I cant take the argument in the function named today(tony)**

Comment: Do you want that `function today` to be called when the document is ready or when someone clicks the link? Or both?

Comment: when some one click the link function today want to work

Comment: And then you want that function to set up another click handler on `#tod`?

Comment: Btw, what do you expect `tony` to refer to in `today(tony)`?

Comment: this just i tried actually i want that date {{this.tod}}

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
const some_func = (mytext) => 
{
   event.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
        url:"/ajaxdemo",
        data:{text:mytext},
        method:"POST",
        success: (res) => alert(res.from),
        error: (err) => console.log(err)
    })
}

const today = (tony) => $('#tod').click(() => some_func(tony))

$(document).ready(today)
```

Comment: how can we add event.preventDefault() there in your code

Comment: in console it showing tony is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

Change javascript code to

```
function today(tod) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajaxdemo",
    data: {
        text: tod
    },
    method: "POST",
    success: function (res) {
        alert(res.from)
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

});
return false;
}
```

Change HTML code to

```
<a id="tod" href="" onclick="today(tony)" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>{{this.tod}}</a>
```